# text is replacing image instead of being shown upon it

Tags: javascript, image, text, replace

I've recently started learning html, css and Javascript and I'm understanding more and more stuff by the day.. Anyway, I have this class in my body that shows an image:

```
<div class="notepad" id="notepad">
    <img src="images/notepad.jpg" alt="Notepad"/>
    <p class="notepad">test</p>
</div>
```

And I also have this function inside a javascript file:

```
function textonimage(){
        document.getElementById("notepad").innerHTML =
         '<p class="notepad">'+"texty blah blah"+'</p>';
    }
```

My problem is that my image gets replaced by the function's text, instead of being shown upon it. I've tried quite a few things but without success. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, you are setting the `innerHTML`, which is the whole content of the `div` to the HTML provided.... with *upon* do you mean that you want to overlay the image with the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the HTML in "notepad". Change the function to:

```
function textonimage(){
    document.getElementById("notepad").innerHTML +=
     '<p class="notepad">'+"texty blah blah"+'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Since they are new and learning it may be beneficial to point out that Griffin's solution is appending (with the += operator instead of the = operator) the html instead of assigning and replacing it.

Comment: @Jake, I'd +1 your comment but apparently I'm not able to.

Comment: Thank you all for your fast replies! You also answered some questions I had about innerHTML by the way :) This one by Griffin was exactly what I wanted, I can see now what I was doing wrong. Till next time!

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the `innerHTML` of the element with the id `notepad`. It won't do a selective replacement, it will overwrite the whole inner HTML.

You probably want something like...

```
function textonimage(){
    document
     .getElementById("notepad")
     .getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
     .innerHTML = "texty blah blah";
}
```